# spring web security sec:authorize url with JSR 250 (@RolesAllowed)

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsr250

Spring security jsp tag `authorize` can be used to check against the url:

```
<sec:authorize url="/details" var="allow_url_details"/>
```

It uses WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator for evaluation. The rules has been taken from HttpSecurity config:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/details").hasAnyRole("OPERATOR","TECH")
            .requestMatchers("/static/*", "/*", "/favicon/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        // ...
    }
```

From other side, I have `@EnableMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)`, and on contoller there is @RolesAllowed:

```java
@Controller
public class DetailController extends ControllerTemplate {
    @GetMapping("/details")
    @RolesAllowed({"OPERATOR", "TECH"})
    public String list() {
        return "details/list";
    }
```

So, we have two places of security allowance declaration:

1. in `http.authorizeHttpRequests` (to get `<sec:authorize url="/details">` work)
2. and with @GetMapping (or @Controller)

Can I (How to) use only JSR 250 way of defining allowed urls, so I can use `sec:authorize` tag without configuring the same urls in HttpSecurity setup?

Comment: No. As they use different ways of securing and the metadata isn't available to the `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then will implement custom AuthorizationManager that uses existing Jsr250AuthorizationManager

Answer (score 0):

Now we have the functionality. The draft implementation looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/ol-loginov/e39dec6aebe5a39bce9dfc473282bbb2

It uses almost none security rules in HttpSecurity (except basic ones), and account Jsr250, @Secured, @PreAuthorize annotations.

It has a little overhead, because we need to resolve controller method twice - here and in DispatcherServlet again